# Multiple sources for SearchFeature in ol-ext

Tags: openlayers, javascript, ol-ext

I am using ol-ext to add a [seach field](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.SearchFeature.html) for countries to my map like this:

```js
map.addControl(new ol.control.SearchFeature({
  source: countriesSource, // of type ol.source.Vector
  property: "Name"
  // etc
}));
```

`ol.control.SearchFeature` does not allow multiple sources as `source`, though, so if I want to not only search for countries but also rivers, how would I provide another source to be considered in the search?

Comment: You will need to create a combined source for the search.  Use the `addfeature` events of each of the individual sources to add those features to the combined source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike pointed out, I had to listen to the `addfeature` event on the respective sources and add the corresponding feature to another dummy source:

```js
const searchSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: []
});

countriesSource.on("addfeature", function (e) {
  e.feature.set("featureType", "country");
  searchSource.addFeature(e.feature);
});

riversSource.on("addfeature", function (e) {
  e.feature.set("featureType", "river");
  searchSource.addFeature(e.feature);
});

map.addControl(new ol.control.SearchFeature({
  source: searchSource,
  getTitle: function (feature) {
    switch (feature.get("featureType")) {
      case "country":
        return feature.get("countryName");
      case "river":
        return feature.get("riverName");
    }
  },
  // etc
}));
```

Note that adding and reading the custom `featureType` is not necessary, it's just very handy if you want to differenciate between the original sources.